# shortcode get thumbnail size

Tags: shortcode, attachments, thumbnails

How to get shortcode thumbnail size?

my code get shortcode thumbnail size in functions:

```
function thumb_medium( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id, 'medium') );
//or wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id, 'large') );
//or wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id, array(100,100)) );
}
add_shortcode("get_urlthumb", "thumb_medium");
```

but [get_urlthumb] always echo full url thumbnail as: `wp-content/uploads/2015/08/origin-image-upload.jpg`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is very close, try to use [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) instead:

```
function thumb_medium( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // return wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id, 'medium') );
    global $post;
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' )[0];
    if ($thumb_url) {
        return $thumb_url;
    }
}
add_shortcode("get_urlthumb", "thumb_medium");
```

Comment: `return wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium' )[0];` that is error code. checking pls.

Comment: Don't you need a `global $post`?

Comment: @DinhTv this answer already in the right direction. Did you try it? I have added link to the codex page on this answer. Kindly read the codex.

Comment: @DinhTv are you getting an error message? Can you give us more information on what is happening when you use the shortcode? @Sisir I edited the answer to load the `global $post` variable and use a conditional to prevent returning a null value for posts/pages lacking a Featured Image

Comment: @Sisir oh, so sorry.That is correct Answers. Thanks
`$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); $thumb_url = $thumb_url[0];`

Answer (score 0):

You can also go with  `aq_resize`  function.
There are second and third arguments are given for size, so you can give any size that's you want. 
Even you can also set these size using shortcode.
Check how to pass arguments to shortcode and pass using shortcode if want to fetch dynamic size for each time

```
function thumb_medium( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id, 'full') );
    $thumb = aq_resize( $thumb, 400, 400, true ); //resize & crop img
}
add_shortcode("get_urlthumb", "thumb_medium");
```